# How to get column names in camelcase in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to run few queries on Oracle SQL developer
e.g

```
Select name AS CandidateName, age AS CandidateAge
from tbl_candidate_details
order by candidate_id desc
```

But In the result I am getting the column names as "CANDIDATENAME" AND "CANDIDATEAGE".

Is there a way where I can get this as camelcase characters what I have given in the select statement("CandidateName" and "CandidateAge") ?

Answer (score 6):

If the column aliases are wrapped in double-quotes, SQL Developer will use those exact values as the column names in the query results:

```
SELECT name AS "CandidateName", age AS "CandidateAge"
FROM tbl_candidate_details
ORDER BY candidate_id DESC;
```

Otherwise, the column names in the query results are always displayed in upper case

Comment: Folding in double quotes also doesn't' work. It is still converting to camelCase

Comment: Well, yes, because that's what you asked for when you wrote in your question "Is there a way where I can get this as camelcase characters" (where "this" referred to "the column names"). If that's not really what you want, then please modify your question so as to clarify your desired result. To avoid further confusion, you should also include a sample of what the result should look like.

Comment: sorry, It is still coming in capital letters.

Comment: Then, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41137314/edit), and add screenshots so we can see what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

SQL is case insensitive and the SQL standard requires to fold all un-quoted identifiers to uppercase. If you want to preserve the case of your identifiers you need to quote them:

```
Select name AS "CandidateName", 
       age AS "CandidateAge"
from tbl_candidate_details
order by candidate_id desc
```

Comment: Folding in double quotes also doesn't' work. It is still converting to camelCase

Comment: @NiharikaUpadhyay But isn't camelCase what you want?

Comment: sorry, It is still coming in capital letters.

Comment: @NiharikaUpadhyay: then your SQL client messes with that. It certainly works for me. See here: http://imgur.com/a/zz4xd