# Oracle SYS_REFCURSOR returns all column name in capital letters not exact column name

Tags: php, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sys-refcursor

I have below procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE USP_MG_SERVICE 
(
  P_ACTION                  IN VARCHAR,
  P_DEPTID                  IN INT,
  P_INTDISTRICTID           IN INT,
  P_INTPOLICESTATIONID      IN INT,
  P_OUT                     OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS 
BEGIN
    IF P_ACTION='GDM' THEN
        OPEN P_OUT FOR
        SELECT INT_SUBNODEVAL_ID, VCH_VALUE_NAME FROM m_admin_subnode_values WHERE BIT_DELETED_FLAG=0 AND INT_PARENT_NODE=1;

    ELSIF P_ACTION ='GDL' THEN
        OPEN P_OUT FOR
        SELECT intDeptId, vchDeptName, vchShrtDeptName FROM m_department WHERE bitDeletedFlag=0 and tinActiveStatus=1;

    ELSIF(P_ACTION='SDL') THEN
        OPEN P_OUT FOR
        SELECT intServiceRegistrationId AS intServiceRegistrationId,intDepartmentId,vchServiceName,stmCreatedOn FROM m_ms_service_registration WHERE bitDeletedFlag=0 and (intDepartmentId = P_DEPTID or P_DEPTID = 0); 

    END IF;    
END USP_MG_SERVICE;
```

And I am calling the procedure with below

```
variable p_out refcursor
exec USP_MG_SERVICE('SDL', 0, 0, 0, :p_out);
print p_out;
```

It is giving output below

```
INTSERVICEREGISTRATIONID  INTDEPARTMENTID   VCHSERVICENAME   STMCREATEDON                  
--some data--              --some data--     --some data--   --some data--
--some data--              --some data--     --some data--   --some data--
--some data--              --some data--     --some data--   --some data--
```

I need all the selected column names with the actual table column name.
Anyone can help me out with this? Thank you

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137314/how-to-get-column-names-in-camelcase-in-oracle-sql-developer helps, they suggest having to give each column an alias with the name in quotes.

Comment: What is "actual table column name"? As far as I can see, those *are* actual column names. If you want to use MiXEd CaSE, then don't. In Oracle, by default everything is UPPERCASE. You *can* create column names in mixed case by enclosing them into double quotes, but - don't do that, really.

Comment: That is why the CamelCaseNameConvention is a very poor choice for Oracle (or any other RDMBS). The SQL standard actually specifies folding object names to lower case. But Oracle's uppercase conversion existed long before the standard. I would just document it and move on too.